# Remove numbers from string in dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to remove numbers from strings in a column

```
ColA   ColB
A.12    dff
B.34    dfa
C.545   dfd
```

Expected output

```
ColA   ColB
A      dff
B      dfa
C      dfd
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(ColA = str_extract(ColA, '^[A-Z]'))` where `df` is your dataframe

Comment: Great thanks. But I tried the same for this dataframe ````df <- data.frame(cola = c("historical.date.1","historical.open.1"))````. But it is returning NA ````df %>% mutate(cola = str_extract(cola, '^[A-Z]'))````

Comment: that's because your letters are lowercase I believe. Try `"^[a-zA-Z]"` as the regex instead

Comment: `df$ColA <- gsub("[[:digit:][:punct:]]", "", df$ColA)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` in base R :

```
df$ColA <- gsub('[0-9.]', '', df$ColA)
df

#  ColA ColB
#1    A  dff
#2    B  dfa
#3    C  dfd
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("A.12", "B.34", "C.545"), ColB = c("dff", 
"dfa", "dfd")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```